# ngRepeat - Sort object by specific keys first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an AngularJS application (Angular 1) which requires a list of tables to be displayed on the page. However certain keys need to be displayed first like so:

```
<div>baz (data)</div>
<div>bar (data)</div>
<div>foo (data)</div>
<div>baa (data)</div>
```

I figured out I need to use the [orderBy filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), however I can't seem to get that working. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

JS:

```
angular.module("MyModule").controller("Test", function() {

    this.sort = ["baz", "bar"];

    this.data = {
        "foo": { /* snip */ },
        "bar": { /* snip */ },
        "baz": { /* snip */ },
        "baa": { /* snip */ }
    };

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Test as T">
    <div ng-repeat="(title, row) in T.data"> <!-- Not sure how I would go about sorting these keys by certain ones first -->
        {{ title }} ({{ row }})
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `orderBy` which unfortunately doesn't work with objects so you will have to write a custom `toArray` filter.

```
angular.module("MyModule").controller("Test", function() {

    this.data = {
        "foo": { /* snip */ },
        "bar": { /* snip */ },
        "baz": { /* snip */ },
        "baa": { /* snip */ }
    };

    this.customSort = function(a, b){
        /* Whatever way you need to do this */
        var sort = ["baz", "bar"];
        return sort.indexOf(a) < sort.indexOf(b) ? 1 : -1;
    }

}).filter('toArray', function () {

    return function (obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {
            return obj;
        }

        return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
            return Object.defineProperty(obj[key], '$key', {__proto__: null, value: key});
        });
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Test as T">
  <div ng-repeat="item in T.data | toArray | orderBy: $key : false : T.customSort">
    {{ item.$key }} ({{ item.value }})
  </div>
</div>
```

[Angular orderBy docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) and
[Discussion on orderBy for objects](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in T.data | orderBy: customFilter
{{ item.$key }} ({{ item.value }}
```

```
this.customFilter(obj){
switch(key){//key is actual value of cases like `baz`,`bar`
   case "baz":return 0;
   case "bar":return 1;
   case "foo":return 2;
   case "baa":return 3;
   default:return 99;
}
}
```